# Set the id of a dynamically created tr tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

I have a table and rows that are being created dynamically into that table as seen below:

```
 $("body").on("click","#addRow",function(ev){
    
    var newRow = "<tr class='tabrow editing'>"
        +"<th><div></div><div><input type='text' class='form-control' value=''/></div></th>"
        // +"<td><div>A"+len+"</div><div><input type='text' value='A"+len+"'/></div></td>"
        +"<th><div><button class='editRow ' type='button'>Edit</button></div><div><button class='deleteRow ' type='button'>Delete</button></div><div><button class='saveRow' type='button'>Save</button></div></th>"
        +"</tr>";

    
    $(newRow).appendTo("#data_table tbody");

});
```

How do I add an id just for the  at the beginning?

I have tried

```
        $(newRow).find('tr').attr('id' , 'row' + someNumber);
```

Comment: `$(newRow).attr('id' , 'row' + someNumber);` since the row is no [descendant](https://api.jquery.com/find/) of itself.

Comment: Off topic: adding an auto-generated ID is an anti-pattern.  You *probably* don't need it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `id` like this

```
$("body").on("click","#addRow",function(ev){

var newRow = "<tr class='tabrow editing' id='row"+someNumber+"'>"
    +"<th><div></div><div><input type='text' class='form-control' value=''/></div></th>"
    // +"<td><div>A"+len+"</div><div><input type='text' value='A"+len+"'/></div></td>"
    +"<th><div><button class='editRow ' type='button'>Edit</button></div><div><button class='deleteRow ' type='button'>Delete</button></div><div><button class='saveRow' type='button'>Save</button></div></th>"
    +"</tr>";


$(newRow).appendTo("#data_table tbody");

});
```

or like this (as in @Lain's comment)

```
$("body").on("click","#addRow",function(ev){

var newRow = "<tr class='tabrow editing'>"
    +"<th><div></div><div><input type='text' class='form-control' value=''/></div></th>"
    // +"<td><div>A"+len+"</div><div><input type='text' value='A"+len+"'/></div></td>"
    +"<th><div><button class='editRow ' type='button'>Edit</button></div><div><button class='deleteRow ' type='button'>Delete</button></div><div><button class='saveRow' type='button'>Save</button></div></th>"
    +"</tr>";

$(newRow).attr('id' , 'row' + someNumber);
$(newRow).appendTo("#data_table tbody");

});
```

Comment: Thanks!
Can't believe I didn't think of that

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes we don't all see the same thing. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

Use `prop` for properties and remove `find` for `newRow` already being the `tr`. You can also make more use of jquerys chainability.

```js
$(
  `<tr class='tabrow editing'>
       <th><div></div><div><input type='text' class='form-control' value=''/></div></th>
       <th><div><button class='editRow ' type='button'>Edit</button></div><div><button class='deleteRow ' type='button'>Delete</button></div><div><button class='saveRow' type='button'>Save</button></div></th>"
  </tr>`
).prop('id', 'test44').appendTo(document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add just along with the `"<tr class='tabrow editing'>"` like `"<tr id="+id+" class='tabrow editing'>"` instead of using $(newRow).find('tr').attr('id' , 'row' + someNumber);

Answer (score 1):

```
var tempCount = 100;
$("body").on("click","#addRow",function(ev){

var newRow = "<tr class='tabrow editing' id='"+tempCount+"'>"
    +"<th><div></div><div><input type='text' class='form-control' value=''/></div></th>"
    // +"<td><div>A"+len+"</div><div><input type='text' value='A"+len+"'/></div></td>"
    +"<th><div><button class='editRow ' type='button'>Edit</button></div><div><button class='deleteRow ' type='button'>Delete</button></div><div><button class='saveRow' type='button'>Save</button></div></th>"
    +"</tr>";

tempCount++;
$(newRow).appendTo("#data_table tbody"); });
```